# Orchestration pyspark scripts in aws step functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, orchestration, livy, orchestration-step

My spark job(we are processing 100 GB of data) taking one hour to complete.in step functions i am using lambda to submit our job through Livy!! and created one more lambda function to get the job status. issue here is , after 15 mins the step function is failed!! any better solution to resolve this.

Comment: What do you mean by "is failed"? Does it give any error message?

Comment: "ExecutionFailed",
    "details": {
        "cause": "Unable to apply step \"jobId\" to input [{\"MasterPublicDnsName\":\"ec2-$$$$$$$$.compute-1.amazonaws.com\",\"jobId\":3,\"jobStatus\":\"success\"},{\"MasterPublicDnsName\":\"ec2-$$$$$$$$.compute-1.amazonaws.com\",\"jobId\":4,\"jobStatus\":\"success\"}]",
        "error": "States.ReferencePathConflict"
    },
    "previous_event_id": "0",
    "event_timestamp": "1647331002032",

Comment: The Step Functions error is `States.ReferencePathConflict`. Sounds similar to: [amazon web services - How to insert the input from a step to a json struct and pass to next step in step functions? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50635671/how-to-insert-the-input-from-a-step-to-a-json-struct-and-pass-to-next-step-in-st)